# Read doc/docx content in python while conserving the font style

Tags: python, python-3.x, docx, python-docx, doc

I want to read the content of a doc file `test.docx` with every word's font style. It contains the following sample para.

............

This is a *test* file with **Bold** and *Italic* Content. I’m writing this as a test manuscript. All I need is to find the **style** of each word while reading it in **Python**.

.............

I'm reading it using python-docx

```
from docx import Document

filename = "./test.docx"

document = Document(filename)
for para in document.paragraphs:
    print(para.text)
```

But it is reading the content without font style of words (i.e. Bold words aren't bold anymore, italics aren't italics).

Is there a way to read the font style of each word?

Answer (score 0):

You need to address two topics to solve this requirement :

1. How to print bold or italic text in the terminal ?

If you terminal supports it (thats not the case of Windows cmd but it will work in PyCharm Python Console) you can use ansi escape code to do so :

```
class FontStyles:
    BOLD = '\033[1m'
    END = '\033[0m'
    ITALIC = '\x1B[3m'
```

2. How to get paragraph font style ?

This information is stored in `font` attribute of style `ParagraphStyle` attribute.

Putting it altogether :

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
    is_bold = paragraph.style.font.bold
    is_italic = paragraph.style.font.italic
    print(f"{FontStyles.ITALIC if is_italic else ''}{FontStyles.BOLD if is_bold else ''}{FontStyles.END if is_bold or is_italic else ''}")
```